# Clearing contents of a fixed char array in C++ after value has been assigned

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Hi i have the following code:

```
char msg[10000];
string mystr = "hello";
// stores mystr into msg
copy(mystr.begin(), mystr.end(), msg);
```

After the code copies, i want to clear the contents of char msg[10000]. How do i do that?

Comment: What's the point of copying the string to msg if you then want to clear it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using modern facilities

```
std::array<char, 10000> msg;

string mystr = "hello";
// stores mystr into msg
copy(mystr.begin(), mystr.end(), msg.begin());

// then clear it again
msg = {{}};
```

Not sure why you wanna copy it first and then clear it, but that's how you can do it. Without C++11 generalized initializers, you can say

```
msg = std::array<char, 10000>();
```

Of course, you can always use `boost::array` instead `std::array`, it works the same.

Comment: upvoted it though if he is learning and the compiler is not new then more confused than before.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want to clear the whole array, then using `memset` as suggested by Andrew is the way to do it. However, if you just want to make sure that as a string it gets zero length, it's enough to clear only the first entry:

```
msg[0] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char msg[10000];
memset(msg, 0, 10000);
```

if you know the size of filled data:

```
memset(msg, 0, SizeOfFilledData);
```